# How to create a save feature for JavaFX game?

Tags: javafx

I am making a simple game using JavaFX.
Like the old Pokemon game, I want to make the save/load features so the users can continue the game after reboot their computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is a bit broad; but as long as you're on JavaFX 8, I would suggest looking into the [NIO.2 tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html). It's most recent of all I/O APIs, and is designed for rapidity. Specifically, the `Paths` and `Files` classes have methods that will allow you to swiftly save data into a file, and read it back out.

For formats, since you're not accustomed to file I/O, keep it as simple as you can. It's often best to label the data, not just store it in binary; primarily for the sake of versatility and flexibility later on. (A minor change in your game shouldn't invalidate your entire file format.)

As an example, you might get a reference to the file with:

```
String dir = ...;
String name = ...;
Path savePath = Paths.get(dir + File.separator + name);
```

Once you have your path, use:

```
BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(savePath, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
```

From there, you can use your `BufferedWriter` to write data just as easily as you can use `System.out`. Be sure to check the javadoc, there are quite a few methods to be aware of. Save you some time. Likewise, there's a `newBufferedReader` method which you can use, through nearly the same code, to read from a file.

Lastly, I recommend staying away from older IO and NIO options which have been broadly replaced; and when you need something like "\" or "/" (depending on your operating system), just use the `System` property `file.separator` or the static field `File.separator`; splicing the characters in literally will break your program on other operating systems, and will completely kill the original point of using Java.

This is a broad answer for a broad question, but I hope I've gotten you on the right track. Let me know if there's any confusion.

Comment: Thank you for introducing NIO.2 !

Comment: so this is what I am going to do:
Store some variables(player health, level...) to the textfile, and then take them from it when the game is started.
Is this the right way?

Comment: Sure. I would just tag it with "HP:" and "Level:" and so on, line by line. Then, as a quick shortcut when you're reading it back in, use a regular expression. There's a handy editor at http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html . You'll want something like "^Level:\\s*(\\d+)$"; and group one will have the level string. Find out more at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Answer (score 1):

I've used the method of writing directly to a text file before for its simplicity, but found that inconsistencies in operating systems can cause problems, as Oberlin said. A pretty sleek alternative is to use an embedded database (It's easier than it sounds). Here's how.

Say your game class looks something like this:

```
public class Game {
   private String CharacterName;
   private int Health;
   private int TimePlayed;

   [Methods, etc.]
}
```

You can make it into what's called an **Entity** just by adding some tags and IDs:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Game implements Serializable{
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Id @GeneratedValue
   private long id;

   private String CharacterName;
   private int Health;
   private int TimePlayed;

   [Methods, etc.]
}
```

Entities are special in that they let you save the entire class itself rather than having to pick out variables and write them to a text file. This sounds like what you want to do, right? Hit the save button and take a snapshot of your program in that moment?

From here, you just need a database to store the entity in. I'd recommend ObjectDB since it's really easy, lightning fast, and free. Also, since it's an embedded database, everything is stored on your computer. You don't need an internet connection or a running server. Just follow these steps:

1. Download the ObjectDB files from [here](http://www.objectdb.com/node/20448).
2. Add the included ObjectDB jar file to your classpath.
3. Add code into your program to connect to the database and save/load your entity.

Steps 2 & 3 are explained in ObjectDB's short tutorials found [here](http://www.objectdb.com/tutorial/jpa/start). There's one for Netbeans and one for Eclipse.

Once you do all that, ObjectDB will store your entity in a file no larger than a text document. Best of luck!